# Is it possible to make a custom project view in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, project-explorer

Can I have a custom project view in `IntelliJ IDEA`? For example in `Android Studio` we get this:

[image]

Now, I want a custom one like that to show only java files and one to show only xml files. It is possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom scopes for that: [Configuring Scopes and File Colors](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html)